# ! Missing $ inserted (normal text in Bmatrix)

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

```
\begin{Bmatrix}\text{Of what nacion.}\\text{Of what countrée.}\\text{Of what auncetours.}\\text{Of what parentes.}\end{Bmatrix}
```

Apparently, I'm supposed to insert $ but I don't know where.

Comment: Why are you using a `Bmatrix` environment to typeset what looks to be pure text?

Comment: I need a double set of big curly braces with 3 or 4 lines of text in between.

Comment: The error is that you have ``\\text`` instead of ``\\ \text``

Answer (score 6):

use

```
\[
\begin{Bmatrix}
  \text{Of what nacion.} \\
  \text{Of what countrée.} \\
  \text{Of what auncetours.} \\
  \text{Of what parentes.}
\end{Bmatrix}
\]
```

or `$ ... $`

Comment: Thank you but it's flushed right.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's best to use math-oriented environments for math material and text-oriented environments for pure text material. E.g., in the example below I use a `center` environment rather than display-math to center the material horizontally, a `tabular` environment to typeset the poem, and explicit `\left\{` and `\right\}` directives to create left- and right-hand curly braces. This minimizes the reliance on math mode.

The first example shows the result of using the default value of `\tabcolsep`; the second example makes do with a much smaller value of this parameter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{center} 
$\left\{
\begin{tabular}{c}
Of what nacion.\\
Of what countrée.\\
Of what auncetours.\\
Of what parentes.
\end{tabular}
\right\} $
\end{center}

%% Second version, with less whitespace on either side of the poem. 
%% (The default value of \tabcolsep is 6pt.)

\begin{center} 
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
$\left\{ 
\begin{tabular}{c}
Of what nacion.\\
Of what countrée.\\
Of what auncetours.\\
Of what parentes.
\end{tabular}
\right\} $
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want it centered, so do I write \begin{tabular}{r}?

Comment: I had assumed you wanted the material centered because you were using a `Bmatrix` environment. If you want the lines of the poem to be left-justified (aka raggedright), use `{tabular}{l}`; if you want the lines right-justified, use `{tabular}{r}`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\text{Of what nacion.}\\
\text{Of what countrée.}\\
\text{Of what auncetours.}\\
\text{Of what parentes.}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I only added the envorinment `equation`, enclosing the `bmatix` one.

Comment: see egreg's comment under the question. That's why it works independent from equation environment.

Answer (score 0):

The `stackengine` package by default, stacks text (one needs to invoke `\stackMath` to stack math, or else use math delimiters in the stack).  Thus, you can achieve it this way, without the need for `\text{...}`.  The alignment of the stack (here left) is specified in the optional argument of the `\Centerstack`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\{
  \Centerstack[l]{Of what nacion.\\Of what countrée.\\Of what auncetours.\\Of what parentes.}
\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]